# Meteor sending click to input file

Tags: meteor

I am trying to trigger clicking an input file element inside a template once a specific link is clicked, though nothing happens when I click on the link, can someone please tell me what I am missing here / doing wrong? Thanks

```
Template.uploadResources.events({
'click #drop1link':function(event, template){
     $(event.target).find('[name=upl]').click();
 }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="uploadResources">
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <form id="upload-2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload">
                <div id="drop-2" class="drop">
                    <a id="drop1link" name="drop1link">Click Here</a>
                    <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>            
</template>
```

Comment: Its not working because you are using .find() but what you are looking for is not a descendant of the event.target. You could use .next().

Comment: @RamsayLanier thanks a lot but can you please explain your answer more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not working because you are using .find() but what you are looking for is not a descendant of the event.target. You could use .next(), like so.

```
Template.uploadResources.events({
'click #drop1link':function(event, template){
     $(event.target).next('[name=upl]').click();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the `trigger()` function to fire the event like so:

`$(event.target).find('[name=upl]').trigger('click');`

Comment: but you may want to be triggering `fileselect` instead of `click` if you are trying to open the file select dialog

Comment: I need to trigger the file input just below the link (name=upl)

Comment: .trigger('click') is the exact same thing as .click() in this case, per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click)